# All my local variables are deleted

Tags: c, variables

In my C program, after I call a function, all the variables in the outer function are disappearing. The program no longer recognizes that they exist, and trying to access them causes an error.

```
void outer_function()
{
  int x = 0;
  inner_function();
  printf("%d\n", x); // Throws an error because x does not exist
}
```

I'm not sure what in inner_function() is causing it, and the function is too long to paste here. What sort of behavior could cause the local variables in `outer_function()` to disappear? The only thing I can think of is that `inner_function()` is writing over `outer_function()`'s memory, but it seems like that would only change the contents of the variables, not delete them.

Edit: I don't think there's really a whole lot more I can tell you. gcc said EXC_BAD_ACCESS and then "warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame," and then crashed. I know it's difficult for you to say what's actually causing it without seeing the whole function, which is why I initially just asked what sort of bug could cause behavior like this.

Comment: "Throws an error"?  At run time?  Really?  You'll have to include some output to show what you mean.

Comment: This should be fine.  Please post an actual compilable code snippet, along with the error that you're getting, and then we might be able to help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "throws an error", and what is the exact error message you are getting? C programs can't throw exceptions -- are you getting a segmentation fault (aka access violation)? My suspicion would be that `inner_function()` is trashing your stack -- there are many ways in which it might do this, so we would really need to see the source for it to be sure...

Comment: C does not "throw errors".   You must be more precise about exactly what goes wrong, and what the message is.

Comment: This is obviously nonsense.  The existence of x is determined at compile time, not runtime, so the variable cannot cease to exist at runtime.  What exactly is the error message you you are seeing?

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing a complete, compilable code snippet, it's impossible to say.  The only thing I can think of is that `inner_function()` is actually some perverse macro that's screwing things up.

Comment: So you're saying this would work if inner_function() wasn't a macro?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying.  I'm saying that a stupid macro is the only conceivable thing (that I can think of) that could make local variables "disappear" (I took this to mean a compile-time issue; it's not clear from the question).  P.S. if you're the one that downvoted, you need to clarify why, please!

Comment: So you really have no idea what's fundamentally wrong with the idea that an inner function being called in an outer function being unable to access the local scope of the outer function? None at all? You couldn't take a wee guess as to why that might be a bit unrealistic? Have you ever even worked in C? Read your profile, you do DSP and FPGA. I am left without a means to explain your brokenness.

Comment: Excuse me?  That's not the problem the OP is having.  It seems that it is you that hasn't read the question.

Comment: As you say, without the code of inner_function nobody will know, but this is a plausible reason.

Comment: @禪師-無: I do not see why you object to this answer.  If `inner_function` is actually a macro, it could do _anything_, and might have an extra `}` that closes the outer function and causes these errors.  If it is in fact a function, then the OP's question is inaccurate.

Comment: All of 禪師-無's answers are gone. I guess he/she decided *not* to stay.

Comment: @Steve - 禪師-無 attracted the attention of a moderator. @Bill the Lizard deleted the garbage answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070168/java-serialization-with-protocol-buffer/4070268#4070268

Comment: One day, Zen Master Wu approaches Jon Skeet, and asks how he can attain Skeet's level of enlightenment.... (would've posted to Jon Skeet Facts, but its been locked)

Comment: Zen Master Wu would not approach Jon Skeet without being burned by Skeet's Pure Aura of Awesome. In layman terms: Jon Skeet's answers are technically interesting and insightful, whereas Master Wu's are pseudo-mystic boring riddles obfuscating the real answer. Let's hope he will come back with humility, having learned from his mistakes: This way, his answers will really be useful for the community.

Answer (score 2):

Are you 100% sure that `printf("%d\n", x);` is the line that is causing the error?  Have you stepped through this?  I would add some lines to print the output of x before, during, and after the `inner_function()` to see exactly where the problem lies.  I have a feeling that you have a problem inside the `inner_function()`.

Comment: Even if a debugger points to that as the problem if there is any undefined behaviour in the program previous to this then it's close to meaningless.

Comment: @awoodland:  I think you are taking an extreme viewpoint of "undefined behavior".  While technically anything is possible, most debuggers can handle a vast majority of "undefined behaviors" with grace.  More often than not, "undefined behavior" is very predictable and understandable.  Its just outside the spec, not outside reality. (otherwise, there would be far more monkeys actually coming out of nostrils)

Comment: @abelenky There are a lot of cases where this isn't true though and crazy stack damage is one of them.

Comment: @awoodland: How do you know the OP is suffering from crazy stack damage?  At this point there is no telling what is wrong since we have no source code and no error message.

Comment: If it's not working there's some undefined behaviour or something else at play. Crazy stack damage would fit what's reported and seems to be one of the most plausible explanations for what is reported in a fairly ambiguously worded question.

Comment: Or he could be making an int x in both functions and the error he got in the inner function confused him into thinking it was from the outer function.  Or it might have nothing to do with x not being there and the OP is assuming that's the problem.  It's more effective to simply do testing than sit around and hypothesize about what the problem may be.

Comment: Any use of x causes a problem. Also, any attempt to create a new local variable and then use it causes the program to crash.

Comment: @Michael: Even the first line of "int x = 0;"?  I know you said the inner function is too big to post but could you maybe give a small code snippet of the first 25 lines?

Comment: @michael See my answer, but this really sounds like the undefined behaviour in question is something in inner_function is either messing with the stack pointer in a bad way or overwriting an important part of the stack.

Comment: @awoodland: You're probably right. I'll check my code to make sure arrays aren't overflowing or anything like that.

Comment: @Michael: Are you perhaps having a similar problem to your previous malloc() problem inside the inner function?

Answer (score 2):

Once you enter the realm of undefined behaviour all bets are off, so if there is any undefined behaviour at all inside `inner_function()` the subsequent behaviour of your entire program and hence `outer_function()` is also undefined.

Comment: If it's a compiler error then there's something else going on, but it's impossible to diagnose from the question. As others have said it's also conceivable that inner_function() isn't really a function which could produce some odd effects, but again without more details this can't be confirmed.

Comment: Agreed, my psychic debugging skills would be that inner_function isn't restoring the stack pointer correctly, so when the value for x tries to be reloaded from memory (using an offset from the stack pointer) it accesses invalid memory.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you declare and define inner_function in different ways (cdecl and stdcall).

Comment: Not the compiler (because it's confused), but built in run time check would, which is provided in debug build.

Comment: Downvote without explanation. On a 10 months old answer. Sweet.

Comment: @Dialecticus - my answer on that question got exactly the same.

Comment: I would give you another vote if I could, but I already have a 1 year old vote hehe.

Answer (score 1):

Though you should still go back and edit your question to add some information about how your program is failing and what "local variables are being deleted" actually means, this is the type of thing that could cause a program to lost the value of a variable from a different scope.

```
void inner_function(void) {
    int x[1];
    memset(x, 0, 10 * sizeof(x));
}
```

This should actually fail when the function tries to return.  This is called a buffer overflow because you have a buffer (a range of memory used to hold something) that you have permission (from the C programming language) to edit, but you edit that and a lot more.  That "a lot more" data is other memory that the compiler expected that you would not edit like the return address and variables in other scopes.

This example is a very general case and it is intended to be easily understood, but it is very likely that if your inner_function does suffer from this type of error it won't be as clear as this.  It is also possible to make a buffer overflow that does not overwrite the return value, so that inner_function would return without failing, but then you might find local variables from outer_function changed (which is what I think you were saying is happening in your code), but to write a usable example of this on purpose I would need to know a lot more about what platform, compiler, and compiler options you were using so that the I could make educated guesses about where on the stack, relative to the top of the stack (which is the current function's stack frame) things would probably be.